# org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, rest

I'm using Spring RestTemplate and facing the problem about error following as:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for 
"https://myservice.com/listeners/60011cbd4a674458d3b26025/90336429462601e7f3326641898fabd9948b349d":
Hostname verification failed: HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier, 
hostname=cowayvina.beeiq.co.; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: 
`Hostname verification failed: HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier, hostname=myservice.`
```

I using post method and can send to server on my local success, my server is AWS EC2

But when I build and send data on dev environment on server it happen an exception as above

How I can fix the problem?

Comment: Did you provide the truststore ?

Comment: hi @AnishB.very sorry i can not provide, because i'm developer only :(

Comment: I was just asking that whether you were using the truststore by code or not.

Comment: good sound for  me, i will try with your suggestion ^^

Comment: Post your code - it will help the community figure out what you are doing wrong. Posting data to a Spring Boot controller on the cloud works.